# problem in post when using flask server + python and react frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to implement a simple frontend, in which you can upload a pdf file and view it, using pdfjs-dist, and I'm trying to send the name of the pdf to the backend, coded with python and using flask. The document appears in frontend perfectly, but when I try to send it's name to the backend with a simple post, I always get this error in the flask server: "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400, and I can't find why.
This is what the function of viewing the document and sending it to the backend looks like in my app.js code:

```js
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (pdfFile !== null) {
      try {
        setViewPDF(pdfFile);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('pdfFile', pdfFile);
        const response = await fetch('/upload', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('PDF file sent to backend successfully.');
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to send PDF file to backend.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending PDF file to backend:', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('No PDF file selected.');
    }
  };
```

And this is what my server.py looks like:

```html
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    pdf_file = request.files.get('pdfFile')
    if pdf_file is None:
        return {"error": "No se encontró ningún archivo en la solicitud"}, 400
    
    pdf_name = pdf_file.filename
    pdf_file.save(pdf_name)
    print("Received PDF file:", pdf_name)
    return {"message": "Archivo PDF recibido exitosamente."}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can't find the problem, so I would be very grateful if anyone could guide me or help me solve it. Thank you!